# Compile-run-navigate traceback without term mode

Tags: term, compilation-mode, testing

I have experimented with emacs' various shells (`term` in combination with `compilation-mode` in particular), and have had performance problems.  For that reason I still use a separate terminal (e.g. gnome-terminal).

My main use case is to run a test suite (python) and then click through stack frames in tracebacks in the test run output (using `compilation-mode`) to have emacs visit the corresponding source files.  My current use of gnome-terminal leaves me manually jumping to buffers and lines in the tracebacks.

What is the best way to do that that:

- Does not use `term`, `shell`, or `eterm` etc.
- Does not noticeably slow down emacs
- Is in good emacs taste (perhaps, just as an example: works well with existing python or compile-run-debug support built into emacs)

Comment: Actually having posted this I realize the stupifyingly obvious answer is M-x compile... I will try that :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`M-x compile` does exactly what is needed here.

Comment: Moderators: I hesitated to post this seemingly obvious / "oneliner" answer to my own question, but the fact is, having used emacs for many years and having learned many obscure emacs details, I was still wasting a lot of time simply because this basic emacs feature was not one I'd ever picked up from colleagues or thought to try!  Maybe partly because 'compile' is not a word that came to mind when writing python code? (even though I've frequently used compilation-mode...)

Answer (score 1):

Traceback highlighting is provided by the compile package.

You can use `M-x compile` to run a script and get traceback highlighting. If you have an existing buffer with a traceback, you can use `M-x compilation-minor-mode` to highlight the tracebacks there.